# How does the heat equation work?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Assume I have the heat equation on a well-behaved domain $\Omega$ (let's say a disc).

But the Laplacian I consider is the Dirichlet Laplacian

$$(\partial_t-\Delta_D)u=0.$$

This equation is well-posed for general $L^2$ initial data $u(0)=u_0 \in L^2(\Omega).$

My question is now the following: Will the Dirichlet Laplacian enforce now $0$ boundary data for any time $t>0?$ How does this follow?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to understand how the solution $u$ has 0 boundary trace even though the initial data $u_0$ does not?

Comment: @StarBug precisely

Comment: One more thing: What is your definition of the Dirichlet-Laplacian $\Delta_D$? As opposed to the Laplacian $\Delta$.

Comment: @Sascha Is $\Delta_D$ the extension of $\Delta$ from $C^{\infty}_C $ to $H^1_0$?

Comment: @StarBug $\Delta_D:H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega).$

Comment: @Sascha: If your operator $\Delta_D$ is defined only on $H^1_0$, you have a problem if $u$ does not lie in $H^1_0$. In particular, your problem is not well-posed, unless YOU specify a precise definition of "solution", and prove that with such definition the solution $u$ lies in $H^1_0$ at all times $t>0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The operator I wrote down is self-adjoint so of course there is a notion of solution by the functional calculus $u(t) = e^{\Delta_Dt}u_0.$

Comment: @Sascha: With that definition of $\Delta_D$, you do not have well-posedness for initial values in $L^2$. More specifically, there is not a solution in your domain $H^1_0 \cap H^2$ for any $u_0\in L^2$. Your question is basically one of regularity, so you have to very precise about your setting.

Comment: @StarBug I said the solution is defined through the functional calculus!

Comment: @Sascha: The solution defined via the semigroup $e^{\Delta_Dt}u_0$ is not well-defined for all $u_0\in L^2$.

Comment: @StarBug see the answer by Giuseppe Negro

Comment: @StarBug: this is a thing that used to get me very confused: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34278/8157

Comment: @Sascha: I am not having a go at you, just trying to help you get a good answer. But for this, you have be more clear about what type of solution you are talking about. Your initial question indicates that you are talking about weak solutions (which would make good sense), but your definition of $\Delta_D$ indicates you are talking about strong solution. As GiuseppeNegro pointed about, you need to specify what you mean by solution.

Comment: @Sascha: Guiseppe Negro gave you an excellent answer on how a weak solution is obtained for initial values in $L^2$. But note that this solution is not necessarily in the domain $H^1_0 \cap H^2$ of your Dirichlet-Laplace operator, i.e., it is not strong. The difference is important to your question, because while a weak solution does not require the initial data to be zero on the boundary, the strong solution does (in a certain sense). The strong solution btw is obtained by applying the semigroup  $e^{\Delta_D t}$ to $u_0$, but for this you need $u_0$ to be in an appropriate Besov space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE. All functions here are real-valued.

Since you spoke of "functional calculus" in the comments, you question can be reformulated as follows. Let $\phi_0, \phi_1, \ldots $ be an $L^2$-orthonormal set of Dirichlet eigenfunctions, that is, $\phi_j\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ for all $j$ and 
$$
\begin{cases} -\Delta \phi_j=\lambda_j \phi_j, & \Omega,\\ \phi_j=0, & \partial\Omega.\end{cases}$$
Notice that $\lambda_j>0$ and that $\lambda_j\to\infty$.

The solution to the problem you wrote in the question is given by the following operator; 
$$\tag{1}
e^{t\Delta_D}f(x):=\sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{-t\lambda_j}\hat{f}(j)\phi_j(x), $$
where 
$$
\hat{f}(j):=\int_{\Omega} f(x)\phi_j(x)\, dx.$$
As such, (1) makes sense for all $f\in L^2(\Omega)$.

Now, notice that
$$\tag{2}
g\in H^1_0(\Omega)\quad \iff\quad \sum_{j=0}^\infty \lambda_j\lvert\hat{g}(j)\rvert^2<\infty;$$ 
this is another standard proposition of the functional calculus (indeed, $H^1_0$ is the so-called *form domain* of $-\Delta_D$), but you can see it directly as follows;
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla g(x)|^2\, dx=\int_{\Omega}(-\Delta_D g) g\, dx=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \lambda_j \lvert \hat g(j)\rvert^2.$$
We can then give the following result.

> Let $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. For all $t>0$, $e^{t\Delta_D}f\in H^1_0(\Omega)$.

The proof is an immediate application of the criterion (2) to the formula (1).

Comment: @Guiseppe: Very nice answer. I would be careful to use the semi-group notation $e^{t\Delta_D}$ without specifying the setting of the operator $\Delta_D$, though.

Comment: @StarBug: That's why I said that these things easily get me confused. :-) I prefer to think in "concrete" terms, Fourier transforms, Dirichlet eigenfunctions... The abstract semigroup theory is too much for me. Anyway, in this case I do think that there is an instantaneous smoothing effect, akin to the smoothing effect of the standard heat equation, such that $e^{t\Delta_D}f$ (defined as in this answer) belongs to any Sobolev space for any $t>0$. So there shouldn't be many functional subtleties, I expect.